# Retrieve AD User info in Spring Boot filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

In my spring boot app I am trying to retrieve the AD info of the user(i.e. name, e-mail, etc) after logging in via the AD page. The problem I got is that I cannot figure out how can I get the user info from the AD in an authentication filter.

These are my pom dependencies:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

This is my `SecurityConfig`:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/azure**").authenticated() // called when AD returns
                .and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(exceptionFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(azureAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)

            .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
```

And this is my filter:

```
public class AzureAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public AzureAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
        String sessionSate = request.getParameter("session_state");

        // This is null
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();


        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I guess I could do it with `OidcUserService`, but it looks like I need to build all the objects myself, but do I really need to? What would be the point of `azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter` then? I have been searching for an answer for hours, but all I could find was either just for logging in or done in a controller. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you utilize graph for this?

Comment: Are you still facing issue here?